# How to fix.. my watch --interval=60 isn't working properly

Tags: linux, ssh, shell, centos

Here is the code I use in my CentOS 5 32bit.
But after this I see only some of files are zipped and a lot of them isn't included in produced gzip file.

```
nohup watch --interval=60 tar -zcvf /home/C/`date '+%m%d%y%H%M%S'`.tar.gz --exclude /home/C/t1/log.txt --exclude /home/C/t1/logs/log.txt /home/C/t1 &
```

Anyone know what is the problem with this ?

Comment: Can you [edit] and add details of what files do and don't make it into the tarball?

Answer (score 1):

You could try putting quotes around the interval time like this:

--interval="60"

Secondly I recommend running this watch inside of a screen without the nohup.